# Fetch only float value from following array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, fetch, precision

I want to only get the value show below in float, how to do it.

```
 array (size=1)
'USD_PKR' => float 123.150375
```

But this output came after running following line.

```
var_dump($obj);
```

So I want to only get

> 123.150375

SO how to fetch only float value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the 'USD_PKR' key in the `$obj` array. You can typecast it to float datatype using `(float).`

Check the following:

```
$value = (float)$obj['USD_PKR'];
```

Comment: Thanks.... I had tried but that time it said you can accept answer after 10 minutes :) Thanks